# Is the Converse of the Radon-Nikodym Theorem true?

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I'm curious as to whether the converse of the Radon-Nikodym theorem holds:

**Converse Theorem:** let $\mu.\nu$ be measures on $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ such that
$$\nu : A\mapsto \int_A f \ d\mu$$
for some measurable function $f$. Then

1. $\nu\ll\mu$, and
2. $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite.

*Proof:* the first part is easy, as
$$\mu(A) = 0\implies \int_A f \ d\mu = 0.$$

---

Does the second part, regarding $\sigma$-finiteness, hold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not. Take *any* measure $\mu$. Then

$$\mu(A)=\int_A~\mathrm{d}\mu.$$

Comment: Oh! Well that was an easy counterexample.